# SSL Error in Ngrok

Tags: botframework, ngrok

I am trying to connect my C# BOT(Bot Framework) through localhost url(https://localhost.com/api/messages) in Bot emulator, it is giving

> POST net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

But when I am trying the same thing with ngrok url(https://2123abds.ngrok.io/api/messages) then it is working.

Comment: Please use `http://localhost.com/api/messages`.

Comment: ngrok is tunneling software that allows your local machine to communicate with your bot hosted on Azure and vice-versa. It is necessary if you want to work on your bot directly on your machine however you would need to push any changes up to the Azure instance.